# How to open my menu with button click on angular8

Tags: html, css, angular, button, menu

This is a circular menu. In the options to open with the touch on the floating button but I get :

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined`

when I run my code. Also the menu is already open when I load this page. I want it to be closed and open when it's clicked on.

```
      <a class="floating-btn" (click)="document.getElementById('circularMenu1').classList.toggle('active');">
        <a><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></a>
      </a>


        <menu class="items-wrapper">
          <a href="#" class="menu-item"><ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon></a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-item"><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-item"><ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon></a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-item"><ion-icon name="help"></ion-icon></a>
        </menu>

      </div>
```

Comment: ViewChild element to use it or use dynamic class atribute to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this approach

in html

```
<a class="floating-btn" (click)="toggleMenu()">
    <a><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></a>
</a>

<menu  [ngClass]="{'active': isOpen}">...</menu >
```

in ts

```
isOpen = false; // set it to false initially

toggleMenu(){
 isOpen = !isOpen; // toggle it as you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but how can I add animation to the opening element in this method?

Comment: check the following link for animation in modal https://medium.com/@josephat94/a-simple-but-awesome-animation-with-css3-for-your-modals-eb24ebe4ab99

Comment: Happy to help :-), please accept the answer if it helped, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I'm unable to find the ID which you have mentions in that `click` event. Btw this is not a good practice to use en angular. As a solution, for the click event, you can call a function in the controller and set a variable based on the condition. Then after you can use `NgClass` property binging in order to close or open the menu.

[Here is the reference for NgClass property.](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)